# how to add canvas to Layout(python kivy)

Tags: python, kivy

I want to add some canvas to Layout, but when I launch this small code it writes **"black"** screen...

I use kivy 1.10 and python 3.6.4

Can anyone help me ?

following code :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Color,Bezier
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout

class AncLayout(AnchorLayout):  
    with AnchorLayout().canvas:
        Color(.1,.88,.71,.57)
        Bezier(points = (100,100,70,70,40,70,100,100),    
               segments = 120,
               dash_length = 9,
               dash_offset = 3)

class MasterApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return AncLayout()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MasterApp().run()
```

***Great thanks for any help )***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are adding the curves to an `AnchorLayout` that you have created and you have not added to your application, the next line with `AnchorLayout().canvas` creates a new `Anchorlayout`. You must do this task in the constructor:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Color,Bezier
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout

class AncLayout(AnchorLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        AnchorLayout.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(.1,.88,.71,.57)
            Bezier(points = (100,100,70,70,40,70,100,100),    
                   segments = 120,
                   dash_length = 9,
                   dash_offset = 3)

class MasterApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return AncLayout()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MasterApp().run()
```

[image]

Comment: Big thanks , sorry for this stupid question :)  (... I am noob ...)